# Ввод-вывод строк

Tags: c, строки, ввод

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[20];
    scanf(a);
    getchar();
    printf("\n\n%c", a);
    return 0;
}
```

пробую компилировать и запускать программы на языке с. выше простенький пример программы просто для теста. в общем, результат работы программы на скрине:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает какую-то абракадабру. пробовал менять кодировку в командной строке,не помогает
подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. буду благодарен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для вывода строки нужен спецификатор `%s`, `%c` - это для одного символа (в который вы и превращаете *адрес* массива).

И еще - для *ввода* он тоже нужен!

```
scanf("%s",a)
```

для чтения одного слова.

Comment: блин, точно, спасибо. немного подзабыл си. и уже был уверен, что проблема где-то в кодировке. глупая ошибка